# Xdebug not catch queries from server in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

If I post a query from Node to PHP app (browser -> nginx -> node -> php (`localhost:9000`)). PhpStorm not catch it.

If request is posted from a browser (with Xdebug helper extension) then PhpStorm will catch it.

Xdebug version is 3.0.2. My xdebug php.ini section (fpm | CLI | Apache 2 | CGI - all the same):

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
```

`php -v`:

```
PHP 7.4.15 (cli) (built: Feb 19 2021 15:42:28) ( NTS )
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.15, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

phpinfo:

```
Step Debugger: enabled
xdebug.client_host: 127.0.0.1
xdebug.idekey: PHPSTORM
xdebug.start_with_request: yes
```

`php -i`:

```
xdebug.client_host => 127.0.0.1 => 127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port => 9003 => 9003
xdebug.idekey => PHPSTORM => PHPSTORM
xdebug.mode => debug => debug
```

PhpStorm settings:

- PHP -> Debug -> xdebug section:
- Debug port: 9003
- All checkmarks checked
- PHP -> Debug -> DBGP proxy:
- IDE key: PHPSTORM
- Host: 127.0.0.1
- Port: 9003

PhpStorm debug config:

- remote debug
- name: 127.0.0.1
- filter debug connection - try with/without, it not helps
- server: 127.0.0.1 (name and host)
- port 80, path mapping settings correct (it works from browser)
- IDE key (session id): PHPSTORM

How can I catch request from Node to PHP in PhpStorm?

### Update

Add `xdebug.log`. From browser xdebug write it, from browser->node->php - it is empty

Cause of the problem was wrong php socket link. When I linked socket to php7.4-fpm.sock , all works fine.

Comment: I suggest to enable Xdebug log and see there: does it try to connect; where it tries to connect, what the response is etc. Also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw

Comment: @LazyOne, I add xdebug.log after your comment. From browser xdebug write it, from node - it is empty.

Comment: How do you make a request from Node to PHP? a CLI or a web request? Maybe it's handled by a different PHP? If it's the same PHP then `xdebug.start_with_request` should take care of that. Try send a request to the page with `phpinfo()` and see how it differs from the "normal" page.

Comment: Thanks. It truly different, `8.0` instead of `7.4`. I execute `update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4 && sudo update-alternatives --config php` . Set `7.4`, but if I stop `php8.0-fpm` service nginx return 502. Socket points to `php8.0-fpm.sock`. When I link socket to `php7.4-fpm.sock` , all works. Maybe you have a suggestions, why socket link wrong?

Comment: Sorry, not a Linux/Mac user and cannot help on php-fpm config here.